# Resize hard disk partition to fill empty space

Tags: gparted

I'm trying to resize a partition (using GParted) so that the first partition (in yellow) will fill the empty space (in gray). Using GParted, is it possible to resize a partition in order to fill all the unallocated space on the hard disk? I haven't found an option for this under "resize/move" in GParted.

[image]

Comment: GParted won't let me expand the first partition (most likely because the linux-swap partition (in red) is in front of it.)

Comment: I think I've found a comprehensive walkthrough for this problem: http://blog.mwpreston.net/2012/06/22/expanding-a-linux-disk-with-gparted-and-getting-swap-out-of-the-way/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only option is to remove the linux-swap partition (I think - but I can't check it - that you could move it to the end), then resize the partition (and create the swap partition again if you removed it).

Comment: A relevant question on Askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143513/unallocated-space-how-to-resize-home-partition

Comment: Is it possible to move a partition (instead of resizing it) using the resize/move option? I'd like to move the swap partition instead of deleting it (if it's possible to do that.)

Comment: I don't know (am not on my machine so I can't test much).

Comment: In the GParted manual, I found instructions for moving a partition: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition However, this can cause the operating system to not boot correctly, in some cases.

Comment: Also, how can you create a new swap partition using GParted?

Comment: Create a new partition of type `linux-swap`.